# Tensorflow accuracy stuck at 25% for 4 labels, text classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The accuracy starts off at around 40% and drops down during one epoch to 25%

My model:

```
self._model = keras.Sequential()
self._model.add(keras.layers.Dense(12, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))  # hidden layer
self._model.add(keras.layers.Dense(len(VCDNN.conventions), activation=tf.nn.softmax))  # output layer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01)
self._model.compile(optimizer, loss=tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I have 4 labels, 60k rows of data, split evenly for each label so 15k each and 20k rows of data for evaluation

my data example:

```
name label
abcTest label1
mete_Test label2 
ROMOBO label3
test label4
```

The input is turned into integers for each character and then hot encoded and output is just turned into integers [0-3]

1 epoch evaluation (loss, acc):

```
[0.7436684370040894, 0.25]
```

**UPDATE**
More details about the data

The strings are of up to 20 characters
I first convert each character to int based on an alphabet dictionary (a: 1, b:2, c:3) and if a word is shorter than 20 chars i fill the rest with 0's now those values are hot encoded and reshaped so

```
assume max 5 characters
1. ["abc","d"]
2. [[1,2,3,0,0],[4,0,0,0,0]]
3. [[[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0]]]
4. [[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]]
```

and labels describe the way a word is spelled basically naming convention e.g. all lowercase - unicase, testBest - camelCase, TestTest - PascalCase, test_test - snake_case

With added 2 extra layers and LR reduced to 0.001
[Pic of training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggXOb.png)

**Update 2**

```
self._model = keras.Sequential()
self._model.add(
        keras.layers.Embedding(VCDNN.alphabetLen, 12, input_length=VCDNN.maxFeatureLen * VCDNN.alphabetLen))
    self._model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(12))
    self._model.add(keras.layers.Dense(len(VCDNN.conventions), activation=tf.nn.softmax))  # output layer
    self._model.compile(tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self._LR), loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                        metrics=self._metrics)
```

Seems to start and immediately dies with no error (-1073740791)

Comment: Are you sure that you are preserving the uppercase/lowercase state of the characters as you embed them into a number? Your example shows your final vector is of length
25 which implies you don't preserve this information...
Also, why don't you simplify your problem and map your characters only to uppercase characters (0s for example), lowercase characters (1s for example), spaces and underscores (2s for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0.25 acc means the model couldn't learn anything useful as it is same as the random guess. This means the network structure may not good for the problem.

Currently, the recurring neural network, like LSTM, is more commonly used for sequence modeling. For instance:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(char_size, embedding_size))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size))
model.add(Dense(len(VCDNN.conventions), activation='softmax'))
```

This will work better if the label is related to the char sequence information about the input words.

Answer (score 0):

This means your models isn't really learning anything useful. It might be stuck in a local minima. This could be due to following reasons:

- a) you don't have enough train data to train a neural network. NNs usually require fairly large datasets to converge. Try using a RandomForest classifier at first to see what results you can get there
- b) it's possible your target data might not have anything to do with your train data and so it's impossible to train such a model that would map efficiently without overfitting
- c) your model could do with some improvements

If you want to give improving your model a go I would add a few extra dense layers with a few more units. So after line 2 of your model I'd add:

```
self._model.add(keras.layers.Dense(36, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
self._model.add(keras.layers.Dense(36, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
```

Another thing you can try is a different learning rate. I'd go with the default for AdamOptimizer which is 0.001. So just change `0.01` to `0.001` in the AdamOptimizer() call

You may also want to train more than just one epoch

Comment: Thanks for response, i've added the layers and am retraining it right now (though seems to be going down to 25% again). I've updated the post with more information about the data, that might clarify what am I doing wrong? Also the data is sorted so it goes label by label, that could have an impact, i believe that fit by default mixes data though